# How to disable `Refused to set unsafe header` in node js?

Tags: node.js, ajax

I send request to my API with  ajax in  NodeJS as shown as:

```
$.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        method: 'GET',headers:{'Referer':MyWebsiteName}
        xhr: function() {
            return xhrOverride;
        })
```

But NodeJS dont send my headers and show `Refused to set unsafe header "Referer"` , I send this request with python and work perfect, How can I disable this `Refused to set unsafe header "Referer"`  in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

thanks from user @robertklep for his [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15267262/12780274).

We just after `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` set `xhr.setDisableHeaderCheck(true);` as shown as:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.setDisableHeaderCheck(true);


$.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        method: 'GET',headers:{'Referer':MyWebsiteName}
        xhr: function() {
            return xhrOverride;
        })
```